# Poor mobile performance after setting background image from file input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filereader

I am currently in the process of developing a webapp using react(gatsby) where users can make posts. Posts contain of an image and multiple text fields. I get the image from the user by using a file type input. I'm using FileReader to read the image and pass it to state. Because i want to show a preview to the author I set the background-image of a div to the in the state saved image. If i do so the application becomes really slow. There is a very noticable lag when typing in one of the text inputs. Does anyone know why this could be? I understand that depending on size the file reader might take a sec to load the image but why does performance after loading suffers that much?

This is my file input:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" ref={cameraInputRef} 
    onChange = {e => {
      e.persist();
      readFile(e.target.files[0])
     }}
> 
</input>
```

This is my FileReader:

```
 function readFile(file){
    // let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      // puts image in state 
      setDishImage(fileReader.result);
    })
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

This is the css on the div:

```
 background-image: url(props.dishImage});
 background-position-y: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height:100vw;
 width:100%;
```

Any help or will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is not ideal for users who select large images (which is often the case, when selecting an image from the cameraroll). You can address this by resizing the image in a canvas and generating a blob URL, e.g.:

```js
function handleFileChange(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    const src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fileReader.result], { type: file.type }));
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => createPreview(img, file.type).then((preview) => {
      console.log(preview);
      previewImage.src = preview;
      previewImage.style.display = "block";

      // Remove in-memory blob URLs
      URL.revokeObjectURL(src);

      // Clean up the preview blob URL when you are done with the preview
      // URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
  });
    img.src = src;
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function createPreview(img, type, constraints = { width: 640, height: 480 }) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = constraints.width;
    canvas.height = constraints.height;

    const ratioH = canvas.width / img.width;
    const ratioV = canvas.height / img.height;
    const ratio = Math.min(ratioH, ratioV);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(URL.createObjectURL(blob)), type);
  });
}

const filePicker = document.querySelector("#filePicker");
const previewImage = document.querySelector("#previewImage");

filePicker.onchange = handleFileChange;
```

```html
<input type="file" max="1" accept="image/*" id="filePicker"/>
<img src="" alt="Image Preivew" id="previewImage" style="display: none;" />
```

You can improve this furthur by using the new [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) API (if the user's device supports it).

Comment: Thank you! I just realized the underlying problem is the performance of  "background-size: cover;" with large files. Will try to resize client side as you suggested.